# Force RTL on LTR devices

Tags: android, react-native

The title says it all. I found a couple of ways to set the application's default layout to RTL using Facebook's I18nManager, but it does that only on second app launch.

code example: `I18nManager.forceRTL(true)`

I do not want to give users the ability to change languages because the application itself is in Arabic. I've searched everywhere but all talk about how to support RTL and not actually use it as the default layout.

Is there a way to achieve this with I18nManager or do I have to do a couple of changes to my native code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

add this line of code to the most top of the onCreate method (before super and setContentView) of all of your activities:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

and sure that you have supportRtl equal to True in manifest.

Comment: Do I import anything?

Comment: no..happily there is nothing to import..but just make sure you have android:supportsRtl="true" in manifest

Comment: This  Answer should be Accepted, thank you +Parazok

Answer (score 9):

First, add RTL support in the manifest like this:

```
<application
    android:name=".application.SampleApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

Then, on your launcher activity add the following code in `onCreate()`.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ar");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale; 
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: could you add `import` statements to your answer?

Comment: I have added this line in my application override class and the app is all rtl now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

MageNative's answer is correct. The only thing is setting the `locale` like that is deprecated. You need to use the `setLocale()` method, like this:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fa_IR"); // This is for Persian (Iran)
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setLocale(locale);
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

You'll need to import `java.util.Locale` and `android.content.res.Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in two places:

**First:** In your Manifest's application tag, add support for RTL like this:

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    ..>
</application>
```

**Second one:** Add this as first line of your `onCreate()` method of your activity:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

If you have a base activity, you can do the same and it will be applied to other child activities.